# ng-circle-progress init on load or by clicking on other button

Tags: angular, progress-bar

I started to use  **ng-circle-progress** lib.  and now I cant run it by clicking on another button or during on Load

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution,   set  lazy: false

Comment: RIGHT!! ..I hope they add it somewhere in the Documentation soon.